# Earthing of HV distribution network

Tags: high-voltage, power-engineering, delta, grounding

I am under the impression that one reason the high voltage distribution network is earthed is to dissipate electrical environmental effects (say, a lightning strike on the line).

For long distance, high voltage distribution (275kV - 400kV as used in the UK), distribution is delta-connected.  I am unclear how a delta-connected line (which, as it is delta connected has no reference to earth) is earthed in this scenario?

[image: How is the delta side earthed?!]

I have heard about zig-zag transformers but know little about them, I am also stuck on the fact that the zig-zag connection is on the secondary, so the primary (delta) would still have no reference to earth.

Comment: Zigzag transformers don't have a primary or secondary. They are a single winding in two parts. They allow current to flow freely to ground, but block any current from flowing between phases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **High-voltage delta power feeds only go to delta loads**. It would be much too dangerous to ground them in any way. Giant inductors and PFC capacitors partially compensate for drifts in voltage. In the case of a short or lightning strike, in-line fuses, and giant arc-gaps clamp some of the excess energy, and giant rotary disconnect switches can take the feed off-line until it is stable again.
2. **Another serious point is that delta power only needs 3 wires**, with their exact voltage to ground unknown, but known to be within a certain range as long as all 3 phases leak equal amounts of current into the air and each phase has equal loading. Running a 4th wire for a neutral would add to the complexity of high-voltage 3 phase power and complicate arcing, corona discharge, PFC control and more disconnect and fusing circuits would be needed. Isolation means disconnecting neutral from a shut-down source and damaged source, so not having a neutral on high-voltage/high-potential distribution wires avoids many potential problems.
3. **The high-voltage loads** at a major substation step down the voltage to maybe 75KV, which is stepped down again at local housing areas to about 7,200 VAC. It is still in a delta format until local point-of-use transformers that supply power to factories and homes convert the power to 120/208 WYE, 277/480 WYE, 120/240 high-leg for older factories, or 347/600 WYE for Canada.
4. **A WYE and split-phase 120/240 configuration has a grounded neutral**, but it can drive delta loads as well. The building electrical engineers have the option of delta/WYE or split-phase power, or combinations of the three.
5. **ZigZag transformers** are another option and use an extra winding to recover the extra tap needed for a grounded neutral. [I found this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigzag_transformer) that goes into ZigZag design in as much detail as you care to read about. The basics are:

> **A zigzag transformer** is a special-purpose transformer with a zigzag
>   or "interconnected star" winding connection, such that each output is
>   the vector sum of two (2) phases offset by 120°. Its applications are
>   for the creation of a missing neutral connection from an ungrounded
>   3-phase system to permit the grounding of that neutral to an earth
>   reference point and also harmonic mitigation, as it can suppress
>   triplet (3rd, 9th, 15th, 21st, etc.) harmonic currents,o supply
>   3-phase power as an autotransformer (serving as the primary and
>   secondary with no isolated circuits), and to supply non-standard,
>   phase-shifted, 3-phase power.

6. **Lower voltage delta feeds** at 600VAC or less can implement a few other tricks, such as corner grounding a phase (mostly for safety reasons on some 3-phase motors), or having capacitors and resistor on each phase to ground in what is called a high-impedance ground.
7. **These wiring and winding 'tricks' do not lessen the shock hazard** so much as they help balance the phases as related to earth ground, and some loads cannot work well with a *floating* delta power feed, such as surge suppression devices and line monitoring equipment that checks phase voltage and current, and phase-to-phase voltage.